# Ubuntu: How to associate a file with a program installed in wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I want to open images using Fast Stone Image viewer in Ubuntu. I have installed the application in wine. How to associate jpg file to always open in Faststone that installed in wine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself:
In open with, enter

`wine "/home/userABC/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/FastStone Image Viewer/FSViewer.exe"`